# Mot pour décrire une situation rare mais importante quand elle survient

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un mot qui pourrait décrire une situation qui ne se produit pas souvent, mais qui quand elle survient est importante (*importante* n'est peut-être pas le mot le plus approprié ici).

Simple exemple parmi d'autres - dire ceci :

> Là où j'habite, il ne pleut pas souvent. Mais quand il pleut, c'est une vraie tempête.

Sous la forme

> Là où j'habite, la pluie est [...]

(si un tel mot existe, bien entendu)

*Je ne parle pas d'un mot décrivant uniquement la pluie, mais n'importe quelle situation similaire à celle décrite plus haut*

Comment: "Il ne se fâche pas souvent, mais quand il le fait il est violent" => "Ses colères sont aussi violentes que rares".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La formulation "rare mais puissante" semble simple et efficace.
"Puissante" à adapter suivant le contexte bien sûr...

> Là où j'habite, la pluie est rare mais puissante

Answer (score -1):

"la pluie est **diluvienne**" semble répondre à votre demande, "diluvienne" étant la forme adjective de "déluge" (le déluge est rare et important).

Comment: *Diluvien* ne convient qu'en contexte de pluie. La question dit bien que ce n'est qu'un « exemple parmi d'autres ».